# Rails: Comment Pagination Issue, Total_Pages Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have a comment model that posts under a micropost like facebook. The problem is that I don't think I am writing the right code under the user show in the user controller and that is what is making this error pop up. Any suggestions? All help is much appreciated!

**Error**

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing /Users/Brian/rails_projects/stateschool/app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb where line #70 raised:

undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc8c2f83468>
Extracted source (around line #70):

67: <%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
68: </div>
69: <div id='comments'>
70: <%= will_paginate micropost.comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
71: </div>
72: </div>
73:
```

This is my current user show page:

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comments = @micropost.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

Thank you any suggestions are welcomed!

**EDIT**

```
<div id='comments'>
<%=render micropost.comments %>
<%= will_paginate @comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of will_paginate are you using?

Comment: @James This version is `3.0.2` The current issue right now is that the pagination is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing
    <%= will_paginate @comments, :class =>"pagination" %>

Comment: When I do that no errors come up but at the same time no comments are rendered anymore but there are the pagniation default links

Comment: I can't see in your templates where the comments are rendered, I expect there to see <%= @comments.each do |bla..| somewhere

Comment: I just updated the code to show it, it is in the edit section. With this I see the comments but it only renders all the comments rather than paginates and the pagination links are on the botoom

Comment: what happens when you do <%=render @comments %>

Comment: ahh it works :) mmm for the pagination links, would you know how I can add a js file so the links just opens up more comments under the preexisting comments rather than go to page two

Comment: mm I just noticed although the pagination is working now, the comments are not showing up in the right area, `<%=render micropost.comments %>` only with this it does but then the pagination is not working

Comment: please make another topic if the pagination is solved, your chance to get an answer on rendering will be larger.